# Pandas: How can I fetch the sum of 'freq' column(shared below) which are grouped by other two columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-processing

[screenshot of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1DJe.png)

```
sum_df = df_new.groupby(['name','city']).agg({'freq': 'sum'})
```

I am trying to group by 'name' and 'city' column and want to sum the frequency values corresponding to that, but the sum() function does not seem to be working. It only takes the first value and does not add the rest. Can someone suggest me a way around this?

Comment: Is freq a string or numeric?

Comment: In the dataframe shown, "name" consist of unique values, so it will naturally take only one "freq" value. It's certainly not a problem with the line of code you wrote there for the exact thing you described to do. I would suggest to check out your data again, and see if this is really what you want to do.